# Confusion on Asynchronous function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I am confused with some topics in javascript.Can anyone explain in detail please.

1.
i)In async function can i invoke a function like (calling myName(str) in caller(str) function ) this or i have to use callback?is it worked as synchronously?that means *callback(str);* will have to wait until myName() completes.

ii)In async function, callback function works synchronously or asynchronously or works after the caller function execution or waiting for callstack(or execution stack) to be empty?

```
function myName(str){
    console.log('My name is '+str);
}

function yourName(str){
    console.log('Ooo!! Your name is '+str);
}

async function caller(str ,callback)
{
   console.log('async function starts'); 
   
    myName(str);  

    callback(str); 

   console.log('async function compeletes');

}
console.log('JavaScript 1');
caller('Mike',yourName);
console.log('JavaScript 2');
```

The above code logs:

```
Javascript 1
async function starts
My name is Mike
Ooo!! Your name is Mike 
async function compeletes
Javascript 2
```

iii)But I think it should log like below.Because caller() is a async function so it will be executed in background & logged later when current callstack is empty.so it(callstack) will empty after execution of
console.log('JavaScript 2').If i wrong how i define which will be log first?what the difference between not using **async** keyword  and using for working as asynchronously?

```
JavaScript 1
JavaScript 2
async function starts
My name is Mike
Ooo!! Your name is Mike 
async function compeletes
```

Comment: You don't have any asynchronous function in your code. You have functions marked as async but that's not the same thing as asynchronous function

Comment: *"Because caller() is a async function so it will be executed in background"* That's not how `async` functions work. An `async` function: (1) returns a Promise and (2)  can suspend execution when `await`ing another Promise. Since you are not `await`ing anything in your example, `caller` will never suspend. Any expression/statement up until the first `await` expression (or the return value) is executed in the same job as the caller.